# change color of highcharts legend page navigation buttons

Tags: css, highcharts

I have a donut chart in angular2 with navigation buttons in activeColor: Defaults to #003399
The color for the active up or down arrow in the legend page navigation. As it is suggested in the API reference of highcharts - [highchart api link](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.navigation)

I have to change the color of navigation buttons from default values to something else that suits my needs. Currently in my code navigation is defined nowhere.It is taking default values for navigation buttons .when i am trying to inspect the navigation buttons currently it shows - [image] 
Any help on how to change the default color of navigation buttons.

below is my code -

```
  defaults() {
        this.options = {

            title: { text: ' ' },
            colors: ['rgba(79, 162, 189, 1)', 'rgba(84, 135, 201, 1)', 'rgba(143, 185, 91, 1)', 'rgba(90, 183, 130, 1)', 'rgba(71, 195, 185, 1)', 'rgba(190, 120, 203, 1)', 'rgba(228, 211, 84, 1)', 'rgba(43, 144, 143, 1)', 'rgba(145, 232, 225, 1)'],
            chart: {
                type: 'pie',
                animation: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth: 300
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        legend: {
                            align: 'center',
                            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            labelFormatter: function () {
                                return '<div style="width:180px"><span class="pull-left" style= "font-weight: 500; padding-bottom: 5px; font-family:Helvetica ">' + this.name +
                                    '</span><span class="pull-right" style= "font-weight: 500" >' + this.value +
                                    '</span></div> ';
                            }
                        },
                        pie: {
                            size: 50,
                            innerSize: 20
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },

            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    innerSize: '40%',
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    slicedOffset: 0,                    
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },

                    showInLegend: true,                                   
                     point: {
                        events: {   

                        }

                        },
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            halo: {
                                size: 0
                            },
                            enabled : true
                        }
                    }
                },

                series: {
                    animation: false,

                    }

                    },
      legend: {
                useHTML: true,
                enabled: true,
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                layout: 'vertical',
                symbolHeight: 12,
                itemMarginBottom: 1,
                symbolWidth: 25,
                symbolRadius: 1,
                labelFormatter: function () {
                    return '<div style="width:180px;"><div class="pull-left" style= "font-weight: 500; padding-bottom: 3px;padding-top:3px;  width: 130px; font-family:Helvetica; white-space: normal; word-break:break-word ">' + this.name +
                        '</div><span class="pull-right" style= "font-weight: 500; font-family: Helvetica" >' + this.value +
                        '</span></div> ';
                },
                title: {

                text: ' <span  style="font-size: 14px; color: black; font-weight: bold;font-family: Helvetica;" >' + this.donutChartInfo.legendTitle + '</span><br/><span style="font-size: 12px;cursor:pointer; color: black; font-weight: normal;font-family: Helvetica; margin-top: 5px;text-decoration-color: "#3572b0">Total: ' + this.donutChartInfo.count + '</span>'

                },
            },

            series: [{
                data: this.donutchartData,
                allowPointSelect: true
            }]
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your legend object, just add a navigation object:

```
  legend: {
    useHTML: true,
    enabled: true,
    navigation: {
      activeColor: 'red',
      inactiveColor: 'pink'
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dksydn6m/

I chose named colors, because I'm lazy.  Hex colors work there also (#ffc0cb).